# Image rotation and scaling the frequency domain?

Tags: math, image-processing, numpy, fft, transformation

I'm writing some code to recover the rotation, scaling and translation of a test image relative to a template using phase correlation, [a la Reddy & Chatterji 1996](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.brown.edu%2F~morgan%2Fpapers%2F(McGuire98)RecoveringRotationTranslationAndScale.ppt&ei=YpbAUMmyCOr34QSG9ICIBQ&usg=AFQjCNHTCoPERm5I41b5W1yH5pBekep0Yw). I take the FFT of my original test image in order to find the scale factor and angle of rotation, but I then need the FFT of the *rotated and scaled* test image in order to get the translation.

Now I could apply rotation and scaling in the spatial domain then take the FFT, but that seems a bit inefficient - is it possible to obtain the Fourier coefficients of the rotated/scaled image *directly* in the frequency domain?

**Edit 1:**
OK, I had a play around following user1816548's suggestion. I can get vaguely sensible-looking rotations for angles that are multiples of 90o, albeit with odd changes in the polarity of the image. Angles that aren't multiples of 90o give me pretty zany results.

**Edit 2:**
I've applied zero padding to the image, and I'm wrapping the edges of the FFT when I rotate it. I'm quite certain that I'm rotating about the DC component of the FFT, but I still get weird results for angles that aren't multiples of 90o.

**Example output:**

---

[image: 10o rotation angle]

**Executable Numpy/Scipy code:**

---

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import lena
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import rotate,zoom
from scipy.fftpack import fft2,ifft2,fftshift,ifftshift
from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots,cm

def testFourierRotation(angle):

    M = lena()
    newshape = [2*dim for dim in M.shape]
    M = procrustes(M,newshape)

    # rotate, then take the FFT
    rM = rotate(M,angle,reshape=False)
    FrM = fftshift(fft2(rM))

    # take the FFT, then rotate
    FM = fftshift(fft2(M))
    rFM = rotatecomplex(FM,angle,reshape=False)
    IrFM = ifft2(ifftshift(rFM))

    fig,[[ax1,ax2,ax3],[ax4,ax5,ax6]] = subplots(2,3)

    ax1.imshow(M,interpolation='nearest',cmap=cm.gray)
    ax1.set_title('Original')
    ax2.imshow(rM,interpolation='nearest',cmap=cm.gray)
    ax2.set_title('Rotated in spatial domain')
    ax3.imshow(abs(IrFM),interpolation='nearest',cmap=cm.gray)
    ax3.set_title('Rotated in Fourier domain')
    ax4.imshow(np.log(abs(FM)),interpolation='nearest',cmap=cm.gray)
    ax4.set_title('FFT')
    ax5.imshow(np.log(abs(FrM)),interpolation='nearest',cmap=cm.gray)
    ax5.set_title('FFT of spatially rotated image')
    ax6.imshow(np.log(abs(rFM)),interpolation='nearest',cmap=cm.gray)
    ax6.set_title('Rotated FFT')
    fig.tight_layout()

    pass

def rotatecomplex(a,angle,reshape=True):
    r = rotate(a.real,angle,reshape=reshape,mode='wrap')
    i = rotate(a.imag,angle,reshape=reshape,mode='wrap')
    return r+1j*i

def procrustes(a,target,padval=0):
    b = np.ones(target,a.dtype)*padval
    aind = [slice(None,None)]*a.ndim
    bind = [slice(None,None)]*a.ndim
    for dd in xrange(a.ndim):
        if a.shape[dd] > target[dd]:
            diff = (a.shape[dd]-target[dd])/2.
            aind[dd] = slice(np.floor(diff),a.shape[dd]-np.ceil(diff))
        elif a.shape[dd] < target[dd]:
            diff = (target[dd]-a.shape[dd])/2.
            bind[dd] = slice(np.floor(diff),target[dd]-np.ceil(diff))
    b[bind] = a[aind]
    return b
```

Comment: I'm actually interested in this as well. If you look a the FFT of the spatially rotated image you see spikes going from where 400 is on the horizontal axis towards the perpendicular centre line. But those lines are not in the rotated FFT. Also you're only plotting the amplitude, how about the phase diagrams? Could you post those as well please?

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if this has been resolved yet or not, but I believe I have the solution to your problem regarding the observed effect in your third figure:

This weird effect you observe is due to the origin from which you actually calculate the FFT. Essentially, FFT starts in at the very first pixel of the array at `M[0][0]` . However, you define your rotation around `M[size/2+1,size/2+1]` , which is the right way, but wrong :) . The Fourier domain has been calculated from `M[0][0]`! If you now rotate in Fourier domain, you are rotating around `M[0][0]` and not around `M[size/2+1,size/2+1]`. I can't fully explain what's really happening here, but you get same effect I used to get, too. In order to rotate the original image in Fourier domain you must first apply the 2D `fftShift` to the original image M, then calculate the FFT, rotate, IFFT and then apply `ifftShift` . This way your rotation center of the image and the center of the Fourier domain come into sync.

AFAI remember we were also rotating real and imaginary components in two separate arrays and merged them afterwards. We also tested various interpolation algorithms on the complex numbers with not much effect :) . It's in our package [pytom](http://pytom.org).

However, this may be super los less, but with the two additional shifts not really fast, unless you specify some funky array index arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the rotated and scaled image results in a rotated and scaled (with inverse scale) fourier transform.

Also note that rotation and scaling are both linear in the number of pixels, whereas FFT is O(w*logw*h*logh) so it's actually not that expensive in the end.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I probably will end up just doing the transformation in the spatial domain, but I'd like to get my head around how it would work in the Fourier domain anyway - see my edit.

Comment: Make sure you do you rotation centered on the right place - depending on you convention, it's the center or the upper left corner. Basically, the brightest point of the image is what you should be rotating around. You can check pretty easily by taking some fairly regular images and transforming both the image and the FT of it and seeing how they are related.

Comment: Hmm, still kind of stumped by this - I'm definitely rotating the FFT about the DC component. Could it be something to do with how I pad out the FFT to deal with edges when I apply the rotation to it?

Comment: Are you rotating *exactly* around the DCT or just approximately? Because the arrays are of even length (for example 8), your rotation around the DCT is going to be wrong if it doesn't rotate around the center of the DCT pixel. I think that the result you obtain is just about what you would get if you rotate around the *corner* of the DCT pixel...

Comment: OK, I tried rotating about the exact centre of the DCT pixel (`fftshift` places it at `ceil((dim-1)/2.)` for even and odd-sized dimensions). Even though the brightest pixel in the FFT stays in the same position after rotation, I still get the weird 'kaleidoscope' effect when I take the IFFT.

Comment: I'm going to have to take a look at this once I have some extra time... this is getting interesting :)

Comment: Really appreciate you taking the time! One think I'm still a bit unsure about is whether I'm applying rotation correctly to a complex array - I've just been naively rotating the real and imaginary components separately and summing them. Is that the correct thing to do?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure the OP has long forgotten this question, but I recently spent the entire afternoon trying to answer this and thought I'd share my result in case in helps anybody else!

The approach which I found to work was a combination of the original post plus the previous answers. Specifically, it is necessary to perform TWO rounds of fftshift/ifftshift; one in real space and another in Fourier space.

The full process is shown here diagramatically:
[image: Fourier rotation sequence]

The code to replicate this is:

```
im = plt.imread(fpath) # this example has shape (1000,1000)

# Pad array such that image is twice the original size
# to avoid Fourier wraparound artefact
impad = np.pad(im,(500,500))

# Apply fftshift in real space before fft2 (!)
fft = np.fft.fftshift(impad)

# Do the regular fft --> fftshift --> rotate --> ifftshift --> ifft2
fft = np.fft.fft2(fft)
fft = np.fft.fftshift(fft)
fft = ndimage.rotate(fft,30.7,reshape=False)
fft = np.fft.ifftshift(fft)
out = np.fft.ifft2(fft)

# Apply ifftshift in real space after ifft2 (!)
out = np.fft.ifftshift(out)

# Crop back to original size
out=out[500:-500,500:-500]

# Take absolute value
im_rotated = abs(out)
```

We can see that the result is almost identical to applying the rotation in real space, with some noticable exception at the edges of the object:
[image: Fourier rotation difference]

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is mad late, but I just wanted to answer the question here as I review my basic knowledge of shift invariance. The problem is that you are extending the Fourier space (as in, accounting for aliasing) BEFORE the rotation. Look at the FT of the rotated image: axial spikes (aliases) appear at the edge where they do not in the IFT of the Fourier rotation.

You should rotate and THEN deal with the aliasing. Because you are accounting for aliasing (cycling your Fourier space at period = number of pixels) and then throwing away that effort by rotating, you are causing aliasing to appear in your final image. Essentially, you are spreading out the Fourier aliases and therefore pulling together the image-space aliases.

The rotation works smoothly for 90-degree rotations because there is no aliasing; the corners of k-space match up perfectly.