# How to rotate a non-squared image in frequency domain

Tags: opencv, image-processing, fft

I want to rotate an image in frequency domain. Inspired in the answers in [Image rotation and scaling the frequency domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744171/image-rotation-and-scaling-the-frequency-domain) I managed to rotate square images. (See the following python script using OpenCV)

```
M = cv2.imread("lenna.png")
M=np.float32(M)
hanning=cv2.createHanningWindow((M.shape[1],M.shape[0]),cv2.CV_32F)
M=hanning*M
sM = fftshift(M)
rotation_center=(M.shape[1]/2,M.shape[0]/2)
rot_matrix=cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(rotation_center,angle,1.0)

FsM = fftshift(cv2.dft(sM,flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT))
rFsM=cv2.warpAffine(FsM,rot_matrix,(FsM.shape[1],FsM.shape[0]),flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
IrFsM = ifftshift(cv2.idft(ifftshift(rFsM),flags=cv2.DFT_REAL_OUTPUT))
```

This works fine with squared images. (Better results could be achieved by padding the image) [image: Squared image rotation]

However, when only using a non-squared portion of the image, the rotation in frequency domain shows some kind of shearing effect. [image: Non-squared image rotation2]

Any idea on how to achieve this? Obivously I could pad the image to make it square, however the final purpose of all this is to rotate FFTs as fast as possible for an iterative image registration algorithm and this would slightly slow down the algorithm.

Comment: I think anything you will do to make rectangular image rotate properly, will be slower than just use padding.

Comment: I agree with Andrey, padding will be so much easier. You need to apply an affine transform. It is equivalent to stretching one axis so the aspect ratio becomes 1:1, applying a rotation, then de-stretching that same axis again to return to the original aspect ratio. Putting all three together in one operation leads to an affine transform, which is more expensive to implement than only a rotation. Though you are already rotating the image by applying an affine transform (why???), so likely it's the same computational cost, once you figure out the transform matrix.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I see... I will try applying the affine transform you suggest, but yes, sounds easier just padding. Well I'm using the warpAffine which as far as I know is the way to rotate images using opencv.

Comment: I just ran your code in python but I get horrible aliasing artifacts... How is that possible that you successfully rotate in frequency domain without artifacts ??!! I would be very curious to know. (I copy pasted your code and just wrote the image to disk, I can send you the code with my aditionnal write and I used a square phantom image)

Comment: @CrisLuengo You seem to understand well this problem, if you could have a look and tell me why there are so much artifacts, I d be very curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion of @CrisLuengo I found the affine transform needed to avoid padding the image. Obviously it will depend on the image size and the application but for my case avoidding the padding is very interesting.
The modified script looks now like:

```
#rot_matrix=cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(rotation_center,angle,1.0)
kx=1.0
ky=1.0
if(M.shape[0]>M.shape[1]):
    kx= float(M.shape[0]) / M.shape[1]
else:
    ky=float(M.shape[1])/M.shape[0]

affine_transform = np.zeros([2, 3])
affine_transform[0, 0] = np.cos(angle)
affine_transform[0, 1] = np.sin(angle)*ky/kx
affine_transform[0, 2] = (1-np.cos(angle))*rotation_center[0]-ky/kx*np.sin(angle)*rotation_center[1]
affine_transform[1, 0] = -np.sin(angle)*kx/ky
affine_transform[1, 1] = np.cos(angle)
affine_transform[1, 2] = kx/ky*np.sin(angle)*rotation_center[0]+(1-np.cos(angle))*rotation_center[1]

FsM = fftshift(cv2.dft(sM,flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT))
rFsM=cv2.warpAffine(FsM,affine_transform, (FsM.shape[1],FsM.shape[0]),flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
IrFsM = ifftshift(cv2.idft(ifftshift(rFsM),flags=cv2.DFT_REAL_OUTPUT))
```

[image: Properly rotated in frequency domain]