# rotation in frequency domain - question about question 64441200

Tags: rotation, fft

Following : [How to rotate a non-squared image in frequency domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64441200/how-to-rotate-a-non-squared-image-in-frequency-domain)

I just ran this exact code (copy pasted from the author's code with just an additional normalization of the resulting image between 0 an 255 as shown)
... but I get horrible "aliasing" artifacts ... How is this possible ? I see that the OP shows nice unartifacted images from the rotation in frequency space... I would be very curious to know how to obtain that, surely you did not show all your code?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from numpy.fft import fftshift as fftshift
from numpy.fft import ifftshift as ifftshift

angle = 30
M = cv2.imread("phantom.png")
M = cv2.cvtColor(M, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
M=np.float32(M)
hanning=cv2.createHanningWindow((M.shape[1],M.shape[0]),cv2.CV_32F)
M=hanning*M
sM = fftshift(M)
rotation_center=(M.shape[1]/2,M.shape[0]/2)
rot_matrix=cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(rotation_center,angle,1.0)

FsM = fftshift(cv2.dft(sM,flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT))
rFsM=cv2.warpAffine(FsM,rot_matrix,(FsM.shape[1],FsM.shape[0]),flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
IrFsM = ifftshift(cv2.idft(ifftshift(rFsM),flags=cv2.DFT_REAL_OUTPUT))

x = IrFsM
x = ((x-np.min(x[:]))/(np.max(x[:])-np.min(x[:])))*255.0
cv2.imwrite('rotated_phantom.png',x)
```

the output image is:

[image]

Also, i ve always been told that it was impossible to correctly rotate (in discrete, not continuous) Fourier space because of interpolation, so how can you explain that?

Comment: Is your image odd in size?

Comment: no, it is even: 128x128 (a shepp-logan phantom generated in matlab from the command phantom(128) and saved thereafter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DFT imposes a periodicity to the image in both the frequency and the spatial domain (some people disagree with this, but still agree that this view is a good way to explain just about everything that happens in the DFT...). So imagine that your input is not the Shepp-Logan phantom, but an infinite repetition of it. When manipulating the data in the frequency domain, you affect not just the one copy of the image you see, but all of them, and not always in intuitive ways.

One of the consequences is that neighboring copies of your image in the spatial domain rotate, but also expand and come into you image.

The simplest way to avoid this is to pad the image with zeros to double its size.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
from numpy.fft import fftshift as fftshift
from numpy.fft import ifftshift as ifftshift

angle = 30
M = cv2.imread("shepp-logan-small.tif")
M = cv2.cvtColor(M, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
M = np.float32(M)

# Pad
v, h = M.shape
v //= 2
h //= 2
M = cv2.copyMakeBorder(M, v, v, h, h, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
```

Now you can apply the rotation in the frequency domain like before. But note that the center of rotation should the pixel at `shape//2`, do not use a true division! Also note that we no longer need to apply a window function.

```py
sM = fftshift(M)
rotation_center = (M.shape[1]//2,M.shape[0]//2)
rot_matrix = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(rotation_center,angle,1.0)

FsM = fftshift(cv2.dft(sM,flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT))
rFsM = cv2.warpAffine(FsM,rot_matrix,(FsM.shape[1],FsM.shape[0]),flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
IrFsM = ifftshift(cv2.idft(ifftshift(rFsM),flags=cv2.DFT_REAL_OUTPUT))
```

Finally, crop the result back to its original size.

```py
# Crop
IrFsM = IrFsM[v:-v, h:-h]
```

[image: Rotated Shepp-Logan phantom]

Do note that the result is not pretty. It is much better to rotate in the spatial domain because, as you said, interpolation in the frequency domain is not really sensical.

Comment: thanks, this is a great answer, and I think many people will be interested in this. Yes I had indeed heard the explanation of double periodicity in spatial and frequency domain that arises from the discretization in both space and frequency for the DFT : explained as a multiplication with a dirac comb in one domain with results in a convolution with another comb in the other domain and vice versa . I you agree I might create another question related to correction in frequency domain at some point.

Comment: also indeed i notice those ringing artifacts which are not present if the rotation is done in spatial domain. Do you think they were less visible in the Lena image because it is a more "natural image" i.e. w.r.t. the phantom which has abrupt and sharp edges causing high amount of Gibbs ringing maybe?

Comment: @SheppLogan Sure, this image has unnaturally sharp edges (it's poorly discretized, there's aliasing), and so there are important components all the way in the corners of the frequency domain. These components are thrown away when rotating (they rotate out of the square), which is equivalent to applying an ideal low-pass filter; this introduces ringing in the spatial domain. You would get somewhat better results with a properly sampled image, or you could apply a window function in the frequency domain to dampen the effect.

Comment: probably you know that there are actually physical Shepp-Logan phantoms build out of special materials for to be scanned in an MRI scanner... its quite funny : it is a "real" phantom, although it has an imaginary part of course.

Comment: any idea about the NUFFT toolbox ? ;) https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/82053/a-simple-tutorial-on-how-to-use-fessler-nufft-toolbox-for-motion-correction

Comment: maybe you could be interested to answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71683509/upsampling-and-interpolation-by-convolution-with-a-kernel?noredirect=1#comment126686669_71683509